# Error when trying to update timestamp in database

Tags: python, psycopg2, aiogram

Code:

```
    resultdate = datetime.now().replace(minute= 0,second=0, microsecond=0) 
    global usrid
    usrid = message.from_user.id
    up.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
    url = up.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=url.path[1:],
                            user=url.username,
                            password=url.password,
                            host=url.hostname,
                            port=url.port
                            )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT into kazino (usr_id, game_time) VALUES (%s, %s) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET game_time = %s WHERE usr_id = %s);', (usrid, resultdate, resultdate, usrid, ))
    conn.commit()
```

When I'm inserting info it`s alright but when I try to update it gives an error:

`cursor.execute('INSERT into kazino (usr_id, game_time) VALUES (%s, %s) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET game_time = %s WHERE usr_id = %s);', (usrid, resultdate, resultdate, usrid, )) psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: ... '2022-05-17T13:00:00'::timestamp WHERE usr_id = 578408714);`

Comment: You have a closing parenthesis at the end but no opening parenthesis

Comment: @BenoîtZu oh, thank you, I will try and say the result.

Comment: @BenoîtZu it worked, thank you (but now it gives another error.)